# Overflow hidden on a child of a flex child

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I have a flex element with `flex: 1`. It's a column, and should take up equal space as it's siblings

This column has two children. One is allowed to overflow, the other is not. 
How can I defined `overflow: hidden` only on one child?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  
  &:hover {
    .child-that-can-overflow {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}

.child-that-can-overflow {
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}

.child-that-cant-overflow {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="child-that-cant-overflow">
      long long text that causes overflow. It should be hidden, with text ellipsis
    </div>
    
    <div class="child-that-can-overflow">
      BUTTON
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>

</div>
```

If I set the parent to `overflow: hidden`, my button will be cut. If I don't, the text of the other child will cause the column to overflow.

Any creative solutions?
Thanks!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsjnyubw/2/)

Comment: button and text is your child element right and you need para graph to overflow button button to not? Am i right?

Comment: I didn't quite understand the question. I need BUTTON to be able to overflow it's parent (col) and text's overflow to be hidden (I.E - not expand the parent col)

Comment: Add `min-width: 0` to `.col`. https://jsfiddle.net/netfp7Lr/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.col {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;//as your requirement
    overflow: auto;// to auto scroll

  &:hover {
    .child-that-can-overflow {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```